# How to update a image, based on a number or value in Android studio

Tags: android

I am working on a android application where i need to change/update the image of a battery(png's) getting updated based on a value (not a functional app but just making an overview of the design)

[image]

How could i make the image updated when the value is changed

`value 25 - image1.png
 value 50 - image2.png 
 value 75 - image3.png and so on`

Comment: Appears like a simple switch statement should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Just make a cascading if-else condition on the image resource you want to use.

```
ImageView batteryImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_battery);
int imgRes = 0;
int battery = getBatteryLevel(); // TODO: Implement

if (battery >= 100) {
    imgRes = R.drawable.battery_full;
} else if (battery >= 75) {
    imgRes = R.drawable.battery_three_quarters;
} else if (battery >= 50) {
   imgRes = R.drawable.battery_half;
} 
// and so on...
else {
    imgRes = R.drawable.battery_low;
}
batteryImg.setImageResource(imgRes);
```

Comment: @cyroxis Ah, didn't know about those. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use setImageResource() method:

```
myImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
```

or with setImageDrawable() method:

```
myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) in XML

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:maxLevel="25" android:drawable="@drawable/battery_low" />
  <item android:maxLevel="50" android:drawable="@drawable/battery_medium" />
  <item android:maxLevel="75" android:drawable="@drawable/battery_high" />
  <item android:maxLevel="100" android:drawable="@drawable/battery_full" />
</level-list>
```

Then you can adjust the level on the ImageView directly

```
someView.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery_level); // Or set in XML
someView.setImageLevel(47); // Or whatever the current battery level is
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use in something like this:

```
    switch (num) {
        case 0:
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_0);
            break;
        case 1:
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_1);
            break;
        case 2:
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_2);
            break;
        case 3:
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_3);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you decoding the bitmap? use setImageResource(R.drawable.img_0)